# Using Seq in emgu c#

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have a self-defined struct of a point (as opposed to `System.Drawing.Point`):

```
struct PointD
{
    public double X,Y;
}
```

I want to get a `Seq` of points, and from there extract the minimum area rectangle:

```
using (MemStorage stor = new MemStorage())
{
    Seq<PointD> seq = new Seq<PointD>(CvInvoke.CV_MAKETYPE(6, 2), stor);
    seq.Push(new PointD(0.5, 0));
    seq.Push(new PointD(1.0, 0));
    seq.Push(new PointD(0, 1.0));
    seq.Push(new PointD(1.0, 1.0));
    var output = seq.GetMinAreaRect();
}
```

However, this code throws an exception at `GetMinAreaRect()`, saying that the input sequence must be 2d points. My question is there a way to get my data format through correctly? I was thinking that I just lack a bit of something, as this code can work for a `System.Drawing.Point`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume following would work:

```
int[] pts = {
  new PointF(0.5, 0),
  new PointF(1.0, 0),
  new PointF(0, 1.0),
  new PointF(1.0, 1.0)
};
MCvBox2D box = PointCollection.MinAreaRect(pts);
```

Additional example : http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Minimum_Area_Rectangle_in_CSharp